# How to click on a javafx slider

Tags: java, javafx, slider, javafx-2, java-8

I have a question.
I am creating an audiplayer, almost everything is finished, but I have a small problem.
I can use the slider, but I can only slide it, clicking doesn't work.
How can i fix this, i have seen some solutions for JavaFX but not for a javaFX application which uses FXML (I am using FXML).
Thank you very much!

Comment: "I have seen some solutions for JavaFX but not for a javaFX application which uses FXML (I am using FXML)." Why shouldn't it be possible to use the same solution with FXML? FXML is just another way to create the scene graph after all.

Comment: It's like they create a new class and extend Slider and add that one to the scene.

Comment: You can use a custom controls in FXML too.

Answer (score 2):

Slider has a method `setOnMouseReleased(EventHandler<? super MouseEvent> value)`, which means you can easily add a MouseEvent handler for clicking the slider:

```
mySlider.setOnMouseReleased((MouseEvent event) -> {
    // do whatever has to be done
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
timeSlider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            timeSlider.setValueChanging(true);
            double value = (event.getX()/timeSlider.getWidth())*timeSlider.getMax();
            timeSlider.setValue(value);
            timeSlider.setValueChanging(false);
        }
});
```

This would also cause your value property listener to fire if you have any registered. You can register one like this:

```
timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
            if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                //do something here
            }
        }
}
```